# Factoring $x^3-3x-1\in \Bbb Q[x]$ in terms of a unknown root

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

So $f=x^3-3x-1\in \Bbb Q[x]$ is irreducible by rational roots test.

The notes say that let $\alpha$ be a root, and then we get the roots $\alpha^2-\alpha-2$ and $2-\alpha^2$. I feel like an idiot being unable to solve for these two, no idea why I can't get them.

---

So letting $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3-3x-1$ we have $\alpha^3-3\alpha-1=0$, and we can try dividing $(x-\alpha)$ out of $x^3-3x-1$:

$$\frac{x^3-3x-1}{x-\alpha} = x^2+\alpha x + (\alpha^2-3) + \left(\frac{\alpha^3-3\alpha-1}{x-\alpha} = 0\right) = 0$$

So we have $x^3-3x-1=(x-\alpha)(x^2+\alpha x+ (\alpha^2-3))$

So we want to find the two other roots in $x^2+\alpha x+ (\alpha^2-3)$, quadratic method is a mess, how should I proceed?

Comment: Is it? $x=-\frac{\alpha}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2}{4}-(\alpha^2-3)}=-\frac{\alpha}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$

Comment: I made a mistake but I rectified it, mostly :P might need some number fixing I'll admit

Comment: @ZelosMalum Apparently the other roots are $\alpha^2-\alpha-2$ and $2-\alpha^2$. Must be another trick to it, since they are quadratic

Answer (score 1):

Since $T_3(x)=4x^3-3x$, our polynomial is just:
$$ 2\cdot T_3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1, $$
and its roots are given by $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{9}\right),2\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{9}\right)$ and $2\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{9}\right)$. The relations between the roots are so given by the cosine duplication formula. Have a look at [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#First_kind).

Comment: I'll check this out thanks, is there a more standard algebraic way though haha. I was trying to find out how to show that the other roots are $\alpha^2-\alpha-2$ and $2-\alpha^2$